# How to block AdSense's automatic ads from certain area of website layout

Tags: html, layout, adsense

I've been using AdSense's automatic ads for a while now and have so far never figured out how to block automatic ads from certain areas of my website-layout.

I'm looking for a way to disable the automatic ads of being displayed e. g. within the menu. Or say directly underneath the h1-Tag.

Is there a way to define areas onpage which Google will respect and therefore not place any ads within these areas? Maybe something like

```
<noads>
Page-code
like menu
...
...
</noads>
```

Thanks for helping me out on that one!

Comment: how is the adsense currently injected into the site?

Comment: I'm using the given Adsense code: <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-xxxxx",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script>

Comment: Can this script code not be relocated to the location you want?

Comment: That's the code for automatic ads that AdSense uses to place ads within the website automatically. It doesn't matter where the code is located - AdSense does the magic!